# I'm trying to show multiple signed urls from gcs to the client and I don't know how to change the console.log to something that works

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a bucket in gcs that contains images so with this code from the server I managed to paginate them and get 10 in a request and at the same time generate 10 signed urls but I still don't know how to send these urls to the client to be able to show them on my web page
For now, I can only send the name of the objects with this code and the signed urls appear in the console

import { Injectable, Options, UseFilters } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AdminService } from 'src/firebase-admin/admin/admin.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
constructor(
private adminService: AdminService) {}

```
async  get() {
    
    let options = undefined;
    
    options = {
        projection: 'noAcl',
          
        maxResults: 10,
         
    };
        
    return this.adminService.bucket.getFiles(options).then(async ([files]: any) => {
        const fileNames = files.map((file: any) => file.name);

         for (const fileName of fileNames) {
            const [signedUrl] = await this.adminService.bucket.file(fileName).getSignedUrl({
              version: 'v4',
              expires:  Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60,
              action: 'read'
            });
            
            console.log(`The signed URL for ${fileName} is ${signedUrl}`);
            
          } 


        return fileNames;
          
      })

     }
  
}
```

u

Comment: Can you tidy this up, especially removing endless blank lines. They just make it scroll for no reason.

Comment: Define "works". Express your problem in terms of *technical specifics* like error messages.

Comment: Sorry I just edited the post trying to be more specific I hope someone can help me

Comment: `retrun Promise.all(this.adminService.bucket.getFiles(...same implementation...))`

Comment: could you show me an example using this in my code please